# Azure search - by search term and page order

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We have requirement 
if i have search term - "pay" 
Expected result page and their order:
1) hostname/page5
2)hostname/page8
3)hostname/page2

Could you please suggest how we can achieve this.Do i have to create some tag field in pages and add search term and their boost ranking/score respectively ?

Sample screenshot
[image]
Thanks in advance!!
Pushpendra

Comment: I am sorry, but I could understand what you need. You need to count the number of "pay" per document?

Comment: As Thiago mentionned, can you expand a bit more on what you are trying to achieve? What is the relation between the term "pay" and the various pages you mentioned? Ranking is based on text-based statistics, so the expected result order would put the documents that have the term "pay" the most first. If that's not what you want, what criteria are you trying to rank on?

Comment: @Thiago Custodio & ramero-MSFT  : my search term is pay and expected search result display order based on search term, which page come first and which page come second,third and so on.

Comment: can you post a picture / sample of your index?

Comment: Singh, you will need to give us more details than that. What is the content of page5, page8, page2, etc. Does "Page5" contains the term "pay" more often than "page8" and "page2"?

Comment: posted picture where is the search term and expected result and page order.
Possibility might our page content (field title,description etc.) not matching with search term but expected result based on search term  given in picture and  page should display in same order.

Comment: My approach i am planning to 
1) Build new index and capture required templates & fields
2) create some tag field in page template and add search term in every page ( based on requirement)  along with boost order ,but problem is that in one search term page A will be the first result page and another search term Page A will be the second result page in order .Is there any way to achieve using add boosting based on search term ?
Please suggests based on requirements any other approach i can achieve this .